# How to Generate Pre-signed url for Amazon S3 without using the SDK

Tags: c#, url, amazon-s3

I'd like to generate presigned URLs for images hosted on Amazon S3 without using the SDK. I'm currently using Rackspace to host my app and you can only do medium trust on their servers, so I can't use the SDK.

Any help is appreciated.

I'm doing this in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually resolved the issue.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=39030&start=15&tstart=0

trick is to do this:

```
    AmazonS3Config s3Config = new AmazonS3Config();
    s3Config.UseSecureStringForAwsSecretKey = false;
    AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, s3Config);
```

Answer (score 0):

What part is being restricted?  I read through http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Overview_of_modified_Medium_Trust

You should be able to add the AWSSDK.dll to the bin of your application on the server.  AWSSDK.dll found in the SDK install directory, on my machine it is C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin.

If that is still not allowing you access, you could run it on your local machine and intercept the actual call being made by the SDK, using fiddler.  Then make the XML call directly from your own code.